# Error occuring with scanner: java input mismatch exception

Tags: java

hoping you can give me some good advice here: I have a game where I need the player to input there name, but it only allows it to be one word. If the user enters more than 1 word, the program gives a javamismatchexception error and it closes out of the program. **Is there a way to allow the user to enter more than one word as their name?** Thanks in advance! And I apologize for the mess of words at the bottom..i'm new to this site and it says to indent code by 4 spaces which I have done, but it doesn't all display correctly.

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWon7.png)

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name;
    int playerClass=0;
    int wincount=0;
    int userhealth=100+(wincount)*3;
    int comphealth=100;      
    int userChoice;       
    int regularAttackD;
    int powerAttackD;
    int quickAttackD;                               
    int playerchoice;
    int advance=1;

    Random b = new Random ();       
    Random d = new Random ();    
    Random f = new Random ();       

    powerAttackD=b.nextInt(15)+25;                
    regularAttackD=d.nextInt(8)+15;       
    quickAttackD=f.nextInt (4)+3;

    System.out.println ("Welcome to the zombie apocalypse...\nIn this text-based game you will need to make decisions based on prompts you see.\nYour decisions will determine your own fate."); 
    System.out.println ("What would you like to be called?");
    name = in.next();       

    System.out.println (name + ", in this game you may need to fight enemies in a turn-based combat style.");
    do 
    {
        System.out.println ("You will now enter a number for the class you want.\n(1)Scout: Increased hit chance for all attacks.\n(2)Brute: Increased damage for all attacks\n(3)Medic:Increased health during combat.");
        playerClass = in.nextInt();
        if (playerClass == 1 || playerClass == 2 || playerClass == 3)
        {
            advance=0;
        } else {               
            System.out.println ("The number you entered is not a class! Try again and enter 1,2, or 3.");        
        }
    } while (advance==1);
    advance=1;
```

Comment: use `in.nextLine()` instead of `next()` for name.

Comment: Awesome! I did not know you could do that. Thanks @Codebender

Comment: @AArisso Sometimes reading Javadoc pays off: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html